# django-filter with django autocomplete light

Tags: django, django-filter, django-autocomplete-light

Has anyone succesfully used dal and django-filter together?
Below attempt is mine,
I tried to use filterset_factory, supplying model class and fields list, then I tried to use futuremodelform.
I got ,

ModelForm has no model class specified.

I think it's just one of many errors to occur.
Anybody done that before, I have to use filterset_factory, and create dynamic classes from arguments, I also want to override widgets so dal widgets can be used.

```
   #testing filterset
    from dal import autocomplete
    from django.db import models
    class PanFilterSet(django_filters.FilterSet):
        filter_overrides = {
            models.ForeignKey: {
                'filter_class': autocomplete.ModelSelect2,
            },

        }

    def pan_filterset_factory(model,fields):
        meta = type(str('Meta'), (object,), {'model': model,'fields':fields,'form':autocomplete.FutureModelForm})
        filterset = type(str('%sFilterSet' % model._meta.object_name),
                         (PanFilterSet,), {'Meta': meta})
        return filterset

    searchFormFilterSet = pan_filterset_factory(self.model_class,self.final_search_fields)
    f = searchFormFilterSet(self.request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset())
    print f.form.as_p()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with DAL, but I contribute to django-filter and have a decent understanding of its internals. A few notes:

- The `filter_class` in your `filter_overrides` should be a *filter*, not a widget. You can provide additional arguments (such as the widget) through the `extra` key, as seen [here](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/blob/v0.13/django_filters/filterset.py#L206-L213). Any parameter that does not belong to the filter is automatically passed to the underlying form field.
- Using an override isn't the right approach anyway, as the widget needs a field-specific endpoint to perform autocompletion. Since the endpoint is field-specific, it's not applicable to all `ForeignKey`s.
- django-filter uses regular `Form`s, not `ModelForm`s, so an appropriate `Meta` inner class would not be constructed. `FutureModelForm` doesn't seem to provide autocomplete functionality anyway - it seems irrelevant?

Your factory will have to generate your autocomplete filters manually - something like the following:

```py
def dal_field(field_name, url):
    return filters.ModelChoiceFilter(
        name=field_name,
        widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url=url),
    )

def dal_filterset_factory(model, fields, dal_fields):
    attrs = {field: dal_field(field, url) for field, url in dal_fields.items()}
    attrs['Meta'] = type(str('Meta'), (object,), {'model': model,'fields': fields})

    filterset = type(str('%sFilterSet' % model._meta.object_name),
                     (FilterSet,), attrs)
    return filterset

# Usage:

# mapping of {field names: autocomplete endpoints}.
dal_fields = {'birth_country': 'country-autocomplete'}
fields = ['list', 'or', 'dict', 'of', 'other', 'fields']
SomeModelFilterSet = dal_filterset_factory(SomeModel, fields, dal_fields)
```

The fields in `attrs` use the declarative API. More info in the [docs](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#declaring-filters).

Comment: thanks Sherpa, you are the star. Except that, I only had to supply a queryset to ModelChoiceFilter, its a required parameter. IF you can edit your answer, it will be complete.

Comment: Hm. That's going to depend on preference. If you want to manually pass the queryset, then it's straightforward. You could also get the default queryset from the field's related model manager, as seen [here](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/blob/develop/django_filters/filterset.py#L481-L492).

Comment: Hey, this is pretty cool, have you considered contributing upstream ? To DAL or DF ?

Comment: Hi @jpic - I'm `@rpkilby` on GitHub and regularly contribute to django-filter. I don't think this code belongs in DF, but you're more than free to add this to DAL.

Comment: For me, just passing the widget to the filter worked. Also I needed to load the JS in the templates of course.

Comment: @jpic - I passed the widget to the filter and added `{% block footer %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js' %}?{% now "U" %}"></script>
{{ form.media }}
{% endblock %}` to my template. any thoughts on why it only shows a blank select box with Django's `------` signifier? the static files aren't showing up in my browser either.

Comment: Maybe the block isn't rendered ?