# Django_filters with django-autocomplete-light

Tags: python, django, django-autocomplete-light, django-filters

I am using django-autocomplete-light with django_filters. I looked [django-filter with django autocomplete-light](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40502794/django-filter-with-django-autocomplete-light), but my autocomplete doesn't work.

**Models.py:**

```
class ProfessionalDevelopment(models.Model):
   Name = models.CharField("Professional Development", max_length=20,default = "None")
   ProfessionalExperience = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='PersonToProfessionalDevelopment')

class PersonToProfessionalDevelopment(models.Model):
   PersonID = models.ForeignKey(Person,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   ProfID = models.ForeignKey(ProfessionalDevelopment,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   Desc = models.CharField("Professional Development Description", max_length=30, default="None")
```

**Views.py:**

```
class ProfessionalDevelopmentAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
 def get_queryset(self):
    qs = ProfessionalDevelopment.objects.all()
    if self.q:
        qs = qs.filter(name__istartswith=self.q)
    return qs
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [url(r'^search/ProfessionalDevelopment-autocomplete/$', ProfessionalDevelopmentAutocomplete.as_view(),
    name='ProfessionalDevelopment-autocomplete']
```

**Filters.py:**

```
ProfessionalDevelopment = django_filters.CharFilter(name='professionaldevelopment__Name', lookup_expr='icontains',
                                                    widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='RSR:ProfessionalDevelopment-autocomplete'))
```

I got an error says 'list' object has no attribute 'queryset'. Then I changed the code to autocomplete.Select2 instead of autocomplete.ModelSelect2 (according to https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/issues/763). Although no error, but I can not type in the text input box. Could someone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You wan to filter model `ProfessionalDevelopment` against it's name.
You need to modify in these steps:

1. Complete `str` or Unicode on model `ProfessionalDevelopment` otherwise the option shows on filter will be `id`.

   ```py
   class ProfessionalDevelopment(models.Model):
      Name = models.CharField("Professional Development", 
      max_length=20,default = "None")
      ProfessionalExperience = models.ManyToManyField(Person, 
      through='PersonToProfessionalDevelopment')

      def __unicode__(self):
          return self.name
   ```
2. Change filter field of `ProfessionalDevelopment`:

   ```py
   ProfessionalDevelopment = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(
       queryset=ProfessionalDevelopment.objects.all(), 
       widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url="yourcompleteurl")
   )
   ```

these steps should address you problem. Don't forget add `{{ form.media }}` in your template.

Comment: Hi, I followed your code. But it still does not work. The filter becomes a drop down list without any values in it.

Comment: @Doris did you add {{ form.media }} in template ?

Comment: No, I did not. What is this for? Where should I add in template? Thanks

Comment: @Doris  the {{ form.media }} will tell template to add js and css tags which are necessary, it's mentioned on dal document.

Comment: After I add {{form.media}} in template, still doesn't work. The filter in front end is still a box that does not allow me to type. Do you have any suggestions? thanks

Comment: Hi, I followed the code and it is working but you have a small typo in "django_filters.ModelChoiceField" -> "django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter". I tried to fix it but my change it was less than 6 chars. Thank you