# Dynamic, client-side update of drop down choices in Django Admin?

Tags: javascript, django, dom-events, django-autocomplete-light, aria-role

My goal is to update a filter pane with server data corresponding to a dynamic input pane.  The filter is rendered by Django Admin's filter_horizontal option.  I thought it might be simpler and more lightweight to use Javascript rather than [django-autocomplete-lite](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#) (also used [here with filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38799632/django-filter-with-django-autocomplete-light), which I didn't understand).

To that end, I found [some excellent code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/247889/limit-choices-for-django-admin-filter-horizontal-interface?noredirect=1) which interfaces with SelectBox.js (SelectBox is used by Django) which I use to update the filter pane after fetching data dynamically from the server based on the entered item.

[image]

The remaining piece to be done is to query the server based on the input.  I wrote an Ajax function triggered by change events on the input pane.  However, capturing events doesn't work **because when 'Input' has [autocomplete](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields) defined**, Django (or SelectBox.js/SelectFilter.js) doesn't use a regular html input element but a span with ARIA roles attached.

```
<span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-id_customer-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" title="John Doe">John Doe</span>
```

Concerning roles such as the textbox role used here, see [ARIA roles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/textbox_role#javascript_features):

> If you are
> implementing a composite widget, such as a combobox composed of a text
> box and a listbox, you need to manage the aria-activedescendant
> attribute using a handler.

According to the [aria-activedescendant docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-activedescendant), it's something you add to the element to allow focus when surrounded by parent elements.  If I just insert it as an element attribute using document.setAttribute() will it break something else in [SelectFilter2.js](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/SelectFilter2.js) or [SelectBox.js](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/SelectBox.js), used by Django?

**But even with that the input element is not listening to events**.  'Click' works intermittently, 'change' and 'input' events not at all:

```
function detectCustomerDropdownChange() {
    /* parent: */
    document.getElementById('id_customer').setAttribute("aria-activedescendant", "select2-id_customer-container");
    /* child: */
    document.getElementById('select2-id_customer-container').setAttribute("aria-readonly", "false");
    document.getElementById('select2-id_customer-container').addEventListener('input', updateFilterList);
}
```

(updateFilterList has an event.stopPropagation() as its first line)

**UPDATE**:
I threw everything at this span, setting aria-readonly=false, aria-disabled=true, and contenteditable=true.  Result: still no response to the 'input' event registered on the span.

Here's the complete code that Django/Select2/SelectBox + my attribute changes generates:

```
<select name="customer" data-placeholder="Start typing a name" required="" id="id_customer" class="admin-autocomplete select2-hidden-accessible" data-ajax--cache="true" data-ajax--delay="250" data-ajax--type="GET" data-ajax--url="/admin/autocomplete/" data-app-label="giraffe" data-model-name="appointment" data-field-name="customer" data-theme="admin-autocomplete" data-allow-clear="false" lang="en" data-select2-id="id_customer" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" aria-activedescendant="select2-id_customer-container">
       <option value="30" data-select2-id="26">John Doe</option>
</select>

<span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--admin-autocomplete select2-container--below select2-container--focus" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="1" style="width: 280px;">
<span class="selection">
  
<span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-labelledby="select2-id_customer-container">

/* THE SPAN IN QUESTION */
<span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-id_customer-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="false" contenteditable="true" aria-disabled="true" title="John Doe">John Doe</span>

<span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span></span>

<span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</span>
```

(Please ignore missing closing span tags, too hard to edit with markdown.)

Comment: I have a partial answer.  The interference from parent nodes is easily prevented by adding event.stopPropogation()  to updatePianoList().   'Click' events now work, but what I need now is an 'input' event to be detected, which isn't working yet.

Comment: aren't you using 'input' event on a span element? i don't think span has an input event

Comment: to edit the previous comment - after some digging, you can do `<span id='my-span' contenteditable="true">span text</span>` - this will allow a user to change the   text value of a span which *will* trigger a `document.getElementById('my-span').addEventListener('input', () => {})`

Comment: @liminor  See my update to the question above.  But the span isn't my addition, it's the way Select2.js or SelectBox.js does it, which in turn are called by Django [autocomplete fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields)

Comment: **Update**:  HTMX looked promising with its ability to [attach events to any element](https://htmx.org/docs/#triggers), but I haven't had success with it in this instance.