# Reverse error in Django Admin when using class-based views

Tags: python, django, django-admin

What's the proper way in Django Admin to display a model (Appointment) with a foreign key to another model (Customer) which may have too many entries (1000+) to display in a dropdown?

Autocomplete is one option, but I also have another field which depends on the customer field which would either have to be updated in real time with the autocomplete or be loaded in the first place with a Customer known at load time.

In order to implement the latter, I inserted an 'New Appointment' link in the Customer detail view (change_form.html template).  The Customer id is passed in the href url to the Appointment creation class in views.py.  That way I can make use of the nice filters for finding the desired Customer before creating a new Appointment containing that Customer as a field.

In the view to which the href points I have used a CreateView or a ListView class (both return the same error) to alter the queryset (per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36950416/when-to-use-get-get-queryset-get-context-data-in-django) and [this doc page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering)) in order to create an Appointment object containing the desired Customer.

But this returns the error:

> Reverse for 'app_list' with keyword arguments '{'app_label': ''}' not
> found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['admin/(?P<app_label>auth|giraffe)/$']

**Note:** ['admin/(?P<app_label>auth|giraffe)/$'] is merely the last entry in the admin's url.py.  So apparently my ListView class in my app's views.py redirects into the admin namespace and loses the awareness of where it came from.  **Maybe a class-based view is not the way to go and I need to use a def view, but then how would I use a url-passed customer_id to limit the Appointment to a single customer, if I don't have the use of [get_queryset()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering), since it's only for class-based views?**

Anyway, the sequence is:

My addition to *change_form.html*

```
<a href="/admin/appointment/add/116" class="addlink">New Appointment</a>
```

Which links via *urls.py*:

```
path('appointment/add/<int:customer_id>', views.NewAppointmentFromLink.as_view())
```

To this class in *views.py*:

```
    from django.views.generic import CreateView
    from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
    
    class NewAppointmentFromLink(ListView):
            model = Appointment
            fields = ['customer', 'location']
            template_name = "admin/change_form.html" 

        def get_queryset(self):
            self.customer = get_object_or_404(Customer,id=self.kwargs["customer_id"])
           return Appointment.objects.filter(customer=self.customer)

          def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            """Insert the single object into the context dict."""
           context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
           context['customer_id'] = self.kwargs['customer_id']
           return context
```

And here's the 'change_form.html' template as returned by Django error handling.  Line 19 is where the error is flagged.  The (unknown) view that renders this is Django Admin's, whatever ListView routes to, I don't override it.  The template is found and compiles ok, but admin/templates/base.py chokes on one of the nodes in the compiled template:

> In template
> /var/www/ptech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form.html,
> error at line 19

```
{% block extrastyle %}{{ block.super }}<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "admin/css/forms.css" %}">{% endblock %}
10  
11  {% block coltype %}colM{% endblock %}
12  
13  {% block bodyclass %}{{ block.super }} app-{{ opts.app_label }} model-{{ opts.model_name }} change-form{% endblock %}
14  
15  {% if not is_popup %}
16  {% block breadcrumbs %}
17  <div class="breadcrumbs">
18  <a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">{% translate 'Home' %}</a>
19  &rsaquo; <a href="{% url 'admin:app_list' app_label=opts.app_label %}">{{ opts.app_config.verbose_name }}</a>
20  &rsaquo; {% if has_view_permission %}<a href="{% url opts|admin_urlname:'changelist' %}">{{ opts.verbose_name_plural|capfirst }}</a>{% else %}{{ opts.verbose_name_plural|capfirst }}{% endif %}
21  &rsaquo; {% if add %}{% blocktranslate with name=opts.verbose_name %}Add {{ name }}{% endblocktranslate %}{% else %}{{ original|truncatewords:"18" }}{% endif %}
22  </div>
23  {% endblock %}
24  {% endif %}
25  
26  {% block content %}<div id="content-main">
27  {% block object-tools %}
28  {% if change and not is_popup %}
29    <ul class="object-tools">
```

Here's the definition of app_list:

*contrib/admin/sites.py*:

```
re_path(regex,wrap(self.app_index), name="app_list"),
```

Comment: The error is on the `app_list` view, so that's what we need to see.  Show us the html template and the view code for the `app_list` view.

Comment: @JohnGordon I've made an addition to the question.

Comment: Just curios - why not use `raw_id_fields`?

Comment: @mariodev  Good idea! I didn't use raw_id_fields because I didn't know about it.  But the problems are a) I haven't been able to make it respond to events in order to dynamically update the second field (2nd paragraph above), [the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77218817/dynamic-client-side-update-of-drop-down-choices-in-django-admin) I had with autocomplete, b) not knowing the customer before page load means that second field has to preload all possibilities for all customers, and c) just showing an id is rather stark.